# Method invokes inefficient new String() constructor from FindBugs

Tags: java, encoding, netbeans-8

Thanks for the help in advance as I'm very new to coding and is just testing some new code from what I've learnt so far.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String x = new String();
    String y = new String();
    int x1;
    int y1;

    System.out.println("Welcome");
    System.out.println("Enter x prediction");
    Scanner scanstr = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner scanint = new Scanner (System.in);
    x = scanstr.nextLine();     

    System.out.println("Enter y prediction");
    y = scanstr.nextLine();
```

When I run FindBugs against this code, I get (for Strings 'x' and 'y'):

"Method invokes inefficient new String() constructor
Creating a new java.lang.String object using the no-argument constructor wastes memory because the object so created will be functionally indistinguishable from the empty string constant "".  Java guarantees that identical string constants will be represented by the same String object.  Therefore, you should just use the empty string constant directly."

I know I can directly declare x as "String x" without 'new String()', but is there any other way to optimize the code without getting rid of 'new String()'

Answer (score 3):

There are at basically 3 ways to write the code:

Your version:

```
String x = new String();
```

The version recommended<sup>1</sup> by `FindBugs`

```
String x = "";
```

The most efficient version<sup>2</sup>:

```
String x;  // No initialization is needed when the first thing we will do
           // with 'x' is to assign a (real) value to it
```

You could also move the declaration so that you can write the last version as:

```
String x = scanner.nextLine();
```

Other versions are most likely derivative of the first version that are even less efficient.  (They may stop `FindBugs` from complaining, but they are a bad idea.)

> Is there any other way to optimize the code without getting rid of 'new String()'

No.  See above.

The point that `FindBugs` is making is that it is inefficient to use the `String()` constructor, and in almost all circumstances it is unnecessary.

It is also probably inefficient and (IMO) definitely bad for readability to initialize a local variable unnecessarily. However, the cost of `new String()` is much more than the cost of an unnecessary initialization.

(The only cases where it might be necessary to use `new String()` are when your application is deliberately implemented to rely on `String` object identity (e.g. you are using `==` to compare strings) and you need to have multiple distinct `String` instances of "a string of length zero".  I am having difficulty thinking of real-world applications where you would want to do this.)

---

<sup>1 - FindBugs is *recommending* an alternative.  It is not "telling you" to do something.  You should bear in mind that the recommendations from a tool like FindBugs are typically based on simple heuristics, and are not always the the best solution.</sup>

<sup>2 - I should qualify this.  It is possible ... even likely ... that the JIT compiler will notice that this initialization is unnecessary and not emit any native code instructions to do this.  This would render the argument moot.  In fact, it is even possible that the JIT compiler could perform a similar optimization for the first version ... since it may know that the `String()` constructor has no side-effects.  Note however that these optimizations only apply in cases where the initialization is unnecessary.  The JIT compiler is not permitted to optimize `new String()` to `""` ... since they actually mean different things.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the response and clarification. I changed the code 'String x;' after running FindBugs to stop it from complaining, and wanted to make sure that is efficient. I'll also try 'String x = scanner.nextLine();' just to see how it works with my entire code.

Thanks again, I appreciate y'all response!